# Como colocar variáveis no dateTime (PHP)

Tags: php, datetime

Olá. Gostaria de saber se posso colocar variáveis nos valores do dateTime. 
Exemplo:

```
new Datetime('$ano-$mes-$dia');
```

Se sim, como?

Comment: Sim, é possível, está com alguma dificuldade em fazer isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta do Guilherme já explica bem o básico, e para complementar, deixo aqui um caminho que me parece tecnicamente adequado, já que você tem as variáveis em separado:

```
   $date = new DateTime();
   $date->setDate( $ano, $mes, $dia );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/fRUV4t)**

Mais detalhes em

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.setdate.php

Comment: Mais bonito assim

Comment: @WallaceMaxters e de brinde, evita o PHP fazer o parse de string. Mas a explicação do Guilherme é importante pro OP entender o problema, então levou meu +1 também :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters bonito seria se o construtor do PHP permitisse fazer isto em uma linha, mas não só a linguagem não permite ter mais de uma assinatura de construtor, mas evita o uso da dinamicidade da linguagem para ter uma método capaz de fazer e decisão de acordo com o parâmetro. PHP virou uma linguagem que não se dá bem com tipagem estática e está estragando o uso de tipagem dinâmica. Não vou falar que algumas classes, essa entre elas, poderiam ter escolhido um construtor *default*, que absurdamente só pode ser único, melhor do que o adotado, afinal até há motivos para esta escolha. Só khda.

Comment: @bigown pior do que ter um só, é os caras escolherem uns bem duvidosos para inicializar as coisas. DateTime é uma classe que quase sempre eu sempre tiro dos códigos, pra deixar mais limpo e mais eficiente. Quase sempre as funções `date()`, `gmdate()`, e as de tempo baseadas em _unix time_ são melhores e mais eficientes.

Comment: @bigown como você mesmo disse, em PHP, o jeito de construir o objeto de formas diferentes é usando métodos estáticos. Você vê problema nisso (acho que vi você contestando isso em uma resposta)?

Comment: É, mas cadê os métodos estáticos da `Datetime`?

Answer (score 2):

O sinal `'` conhecido como aspas simples ou apostrofo não aceita variáveis, como esta no seu exemplo:

```
new Datetime('$ano-$mes-$dia');
```

Apenas "aspas normais" aceitam, então você pode fazer assim:

```
new Datetime("$ano-$mes-$dia");
```

Você também pode concatenar:

```
new Datetime( $ano . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dia );
```

Exemplo de uso, adicionando mais um dia:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime("$ano-$mes-$dia");
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

### Documentação do DataTime:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

Para tentar fazer de um jeito mais simplificado do que as duas respostas apresentadas, se você estiver usando uma versão igual ou maior que o 5.4, pode fazer assim

```
$date = (new DateTime())->setDate( $ano, $mes, $dia );
```